# Why does \foreach expansion in the \draw command not work if the -- operator is at the end?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Look at this MWE here,

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\PolarToX}[2]{ {(#1)*cos(#2)}, {(#1)*sin(#2)} }
\begin{document}
\tikz{
\draw [very thick] (0, 0) \foreach \i in {0, 1, ..., 360} {-- (\PolarToX{4+.3*cos(20*\i)}{\i})};
}
\end{document}
```

which outputs something like this,

[image: a biscuit]

I don't want the line in the middle. So I tried doing something like,

```tex
\draw [very thick] \foreach \i in {0, 1, ..., 360} { (\PolarToX{4+.3*cos(20*\i)}{\i}) -- } cycle;
```

which doesn't work. Neither does this:

```tex
\draw [very thick] (0,0) \foreach \i in {0, 1, ..., 360} { (\PolarToX{4+.3*cos(20*\i)}{\i}) -- } cycle;
```

Why does neither of the above work? What would be the correct
way to do this?

Comment: As an aside, a `--` needs to *see* a coordinate specification (after some nodes maybe). It can't be a macro: `-- \foo`. And it can't be the end of path specification, i.e. the way `\foreach` feeds the path segment to the TikZ parser. That's just the explanation why your last two examples simply fail. It's not a valid foreach/TikZ path specification. (One could workaround this but I think the answers provide better solutions.)

Answer (score 5):

Two things:

1. TikZ has polar coordinates: `(<angle>:<radius>)` or even `(<angle>:<x radius> and <y radius>)`.
2. TikZ has a plot function which

   - is basically a loop in itself
   - but handles the start and the end of your path with care.

This means, you can just do

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \draw[very thick]
    plot[samples at = {0, ..., 359}, sharp cycle] (\x:{4+.3*cos(20*\x)});
\end{document}
```

and get

[image]

---

Here I'm using the `samples at` key (notice the `...` notation!) to explicitly describe which values for `\x` should be used.
Without any other options, it would issue just a move to to the first coordinate (unless you use `-- plot`) and then a line to (`--`) to all the others.

The `sharp cycle` key will add a `-- cycle` at the end.

**Note:** It doesn't really, it works on the PGF level but that's basically how the `plot` interface works.

Comment: I know about the polar co-ordinates in tikz, but that was not my question. I was just a MWE. I wanted to know the mechanism behind the `\foreach` expansions and why `\draw \foreach \i in {...} { -- (\i, i)}` works while, `\draw \foreach \i in {...} { (\i, i) --} cycle` doesn't. I am sorry if the question was not clear.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the point (0,0) with the first point. Like so:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\PolarToX}[2]{ {(#1)*cos(#2)}, {(#1)*sin(#2)} }
\begin{document}
\tikz{
        \draw [very thick] (\PolarToX{4.3}{0}) \foreach \i in { 1, ..., 360} {-- (\PolarToX{4+.3*cos(20*\i)}{\i})};
}
\end{document}
```

---

The reason what you tried didn't work is that after the `\foreach` expansion, your expressions always end up starting with `--` or have a `--` dangling at the end, neither of which conform to the correct syntax for `\draw` in tikz.

Comment: How is it dangling? If `\foreach \i in {0, 1, 2}{ (\i, \i) -- }` expands to `(0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,2) --`, then `\draw \foreach \i {0, 1, 2}{ (\i, \i) -- } cycle;` should expand to `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,2) -- cycle;` shouldn't it?

Comment: I didn't notice that you inserted `cycle` at the end; my bad. I think [your question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686619/why-does-foreach-expansion-in-the-draw-command-not-work-if-the-operator-is/686634?noredirect=1#comment1704050_686640) is a good one; but it was lost in the formulation you gave above. It may help to ask a new question specifically contrasting those two statements.

Answer (score 3):

With `\draw [very thick] \foreach \i in {0,...,5} {--node[pos=0,below] {\i} ++(1,0)};` the pattern starts with `\i=1`, so just remove the node `(0,0)` To close, we put 1 after 360 `\foreach \i in {0, ..., 360,1}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\PolarToX}[2]{ {(#1)*cos(#2)}, {(#1)*sin(#2)} }
\begin{document}
\tikz{
\draw [very thick]  \foreach \i in {0, ..., 360,1} {-- (\PolarToX{4+.3*cos(20*\i)}{\i})};
}

% \bigskip
% \tikz{
% \draw [very thick] \foreach \i in {0,...,5} {--node[pos=0,below] {\i} ++(1,0)};
% }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your expansion of `\foreach` has a dangling `--` at the beginning. Why does it work, while my expansion without a dangling `--` doesn't?

Comment: By trying, it worked, luck no doubt. In the first comment Qrrbrbirlbel gives an explanation and his answer performs very well.